# Searching for a stream in EventStore

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, eventstoredb

Is it possible to search for a stream not by StreamId but by some another Stream attribute? For example, if every stream has CustomerId in the Headers and I would like to search for all the streams with the particular CustomerId.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Event stores are designed to support retrieval exclusively by the key of the entity. To support retrieval by other attributes, data is indexed in an eventually consistent, de-normalized fashion specifically for each use case and in a separate place. So the event-store only stores events and to support querying of any sort indexed projections are utilized. These are sort of like persistent views in a relational database but they can be stored in a simple key-value store. Together, an event-store and a projection store constitute part of the infrastructure behind a [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) + [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) architecture. Take a look [here](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/) and the rest of that blog for more on this subject.

Comment: Wrong . From your point of view it may be true. But actually, there is a pretty popular implementation of an event store that allows to query aggregates by other attributes than the aggregate id. Check getEventStore. It actually seemd pretty unusable such an implementation of event store. Or usable in very rare and specific cases. GetEventStore is the proper way to go for small-medium applications using CQRS .

Comment: Wrong about what? Yes, the EventStore projection system can allow you to index events based on any attribute in the event, however the issue remains that this index is eventually consistent - it is updated in the background. In practice, a better option is to store secondary indexes in fast atomic storage such as Redis.

Comment: A lookup table in theory may be good. But in practice, for an event store with milions/bilions of events to generate such a lookup table is not feasible. Projections allow you to filter the events . So no need to generate/partition such a lookup table. Since you can generate snapshots and take advantage of projections , it's the best way to go when it comes to searching aggregates by any attribute . You were wrong at the first line : "Event stores are designed to support retrieval exclusively by the key of the entity."

Comment: Also from what I know projections in getEventStore are not used to only generate other events. They are used to simply retunr some result, and use that result in your application to for example, build specific aggregates. Like a querying mechanism same as the WHERE clause in sql language.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you're trying to use the event store incorrectly. An event store is built only for saving and reading streams of committed events for rebuilding event-sourced aggregates. Implementations provide headers for conveniently implementing infrastructure concerns, such as request/response correlation IDs, auditing, security, and the like. If you find yourself putting business attributes in there -- like a customer id -- then you may need to instead build a read model as suggested by @eulerfx.

If it's an ID you're looking for, then you should consider making CustomerID the actual event stream ID for that customer. Loading a particular customer by its ID is exactly what you'd expect an event store to do.

Answer (score 2):

EventStore now has projections which can do what you are looking for. Please see this blog for details

http://geteventstore.com/blog/20130227/projections-6-an-indexing-use-case/

Comment: Creating steams is cheap so having lots of other streams such as :CustomerId-123 created by a projection each time an event comes in (for processing) is one way to achieve the index you are after without much performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is probably not the most efficient way to find something, if you do need a list of streams so you can search them or find a particular one, there is a $streams system projection, but it needs enabling first before you can use it using something like this powershell:

```
uri$ = http://${EventStoreIP}:${EventStoreHttpPort}/projection/${projection}/command/enable

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 90 -Headers @{
    Authorization = Get-BasicAuthCredentials
}
```

where $projection is '$streams'. Look also at the other system projections that can be enabled the same way, which may provide what you need more precisely, which are documented here: https://eventstore.org/docs/projections/system-projections/